# Applying new custom heading styles to Google Drive documents

Tags: google-drive

How do I apply newly changed heading styles to selected (or at least one at a time) existing documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically apply all of your newly-set default styles to your doc. What you would need to do is:

- Open the document
- Go into the styles menu in the toolbar (default text is "Normal Text")
- Open the options menu and select "Use my default styles"

This will apply all of your current default styles **to the menu only**. From there you will still need to click into each piece of header text you'd like to change and apply the formatting manually (e.g. using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to apply Heading 3)